# Spring 3.1 controller returning the name of an HTML page - will it work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I apologize in advance if this isn't the right forum to ask this... but I'm perplexed.

We're using Spring 3.1.1 in a new website.  The team building it is, well, inexperienced.

I ran into this code:

```
public String signOut(@ModelAttribute("state") State state, Model model) {
    // useful stuff here
    return "signOut.html";
}
```

and

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
</bean>
```

However, the name of the JSP file we created is `/WEB-INF/jsp/signOut.jspx` (html is not part of the name).

To my surprise - this actually works.  InternalViewResolver returns `/WEB-INF/jsp/signOut.html.jspx` as expected.

I would have thought that Spring, at some point, wouldn't have been able to find the compiled JSP servlet created for `signOut.html.jspx`, but it seems to be finding it just fine!

How is this possibly working?  And what damage would it be doing?

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually everything works as designed. From the controller you can either return view name (as it is in this case), `View` instance encapsulating view name or `ModelAndView` encapsulating both view and model.

In your case `String` return value means *view name*. So Spring uses `ViewResolver` abstraction to translate view name to actual view file. The `prefix` and `suffix` properties are configured so that you don't have to return fully-qualified file path from controller. Prefix and suffix are applied and Spring finds the view file in the right place.

What exactly is surprising for you?

Comment: What surprises me is that the view resolves to "/WEB-INF/jsp/signOut.html.jspx - which is not the correct name of the JSP file.  I would expect the servlet compiled from signOut.html.jspx would not be the same name as the servlet compiled from signOut.jspx.

Comment: @Jay: You mean you have no `/WEB-INF/jsp/signOut.html.jspx` file in your project?